# JNetPcap open pcap from InputStream

Tags: c++, inputstream, libpcap, jnetpcap

Is there a way to open an offline Pcap from an InputStream and not from a local file?

In the documentation it say that you can use `pcap_fopen_offline()` to open Pcap from an open stream but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation come with a sample? At least, what's the signature of this function? It probably uses a file handle, and not a `std::ifstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pcap_fopen_offline(3)` is a C API of which JNetPCap works as a wrapper (you should have noticed this fact because naming convention is so different from Java API!)  You don't have a direct access to it unless you code in C without JNetPCap (maybe you can access it with JNI/JNA, but that's no different from coding in C)

Moreover, when a document about C API talks about "stream", it's almost always a "file stream" in C's terminology.  It doesn't necessarily mean a data stream from a file in a filesystem, but you basically need to be fluent with C to use it anything other than STDIN/OUT or files in a filesystem.  I quickly went through Javadoc of JNetPCap, but I don't think it can do the work of translating a general `InputStream` into C's file stream for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks, so if i'm getting the file from DB as an InputStream I will have to write it to the disk and then open it? or there is any way to get around this?

Comment: @AmirRossert I'm afraid that is the only way.  I `grep`ped for `pcap_fopen_offline` in the source directory of `jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1`, in vain.  JNetPCap only calls `pcap_open_offline()`.